# Обучался(АСЬ) или обучался(ЛАСЬ)?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно написать в Форме документа об образовании: 
*обучался(АСЬ)* или *обучался(ЛАСЬ)*?

Answer (score 3):

Обычно печатается то, что не изменяется, а то, что меняется, дописывают ручкой.

...обучал_____....

Можно напечатать с вариантами выбора, тогда заполняющий форму подчеркнёт выбранное:

....обучал(ся/ась)....